# Joomla component loading throws exception

Tags: php

I'm working on a Joomla 4 website which is migrated from Joomla 3.11. Everything else is working fine except one page. These page is also rendered and further it loads data from a ajax request from the same server. The ajax request is failing. While troubleshooting the issue I found that jquery is trying to load PHP files directly. This is the jquery code which is loading php file.

```
jQuery.get( "components/com_mycomp/lib/common/load.php", {scope:"get_first_site"}, function(first_site) { .... }
```

When I navigate to this url (http://localhost/components/com_mycomp/lib/common/load.php) manually from the browser, it throws and exception: "Failed to start application"
[image]

Comment: Sorry, posted in wrong forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you are trying to load Joomla 4 using the code for Joomla 3 which I suspect is happening in the `j_load.php` file.

A similar question was answered recently, [getMailer gives "Failed to start application" exception after updating to Joomla4, how do I fix it?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33107/getmailer-gives-failed-to-start-application-exception-after-updating-to-joomla) that provides code that you could use to replace the Joomla 3 loading code.

**Edit: 24/06/2023**
Since I originally answered this question I have learnt more and posted a more complete answer in this post here with sample code for calling an instance of Joomla 4.

[How to create an instance of the Joomla CMS from the browser or the command line](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33140/how-to-create-an-instance-of-the-joomla-cms-from-the-browser-or-the-command-line/33141?noredirect=1#comment40804_33141)

Comment: Thanks @Irata. I managed to execute my code by using define('NO_SESSION', 1); in my php file which further calls j_load.php. does it have any side-effect?

Comment: That would depend on whether your extension needs to have or uses Sessions for subsequent access but if it is working for you than you are probably okay.