# Upgrade Joomla CLi script to handle bulk import of items into articles

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, articles, cli, api

I am upgrading a client's CLi script that is used to automatically bulk import news items into Joomla articles. The code was originally programmed for Joomla 3 and now needs to support Joomla 4.

I have completed quite a few upgrades, but am now stuck looping through the news item data and storing it using the `Content::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel')` method. I have included my code below for reference.

**Updated September 18**

Current use statements

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Administrator\Model\ArticleModel;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Content;
use Joomla\CMS\Filter\OutputFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand;
```

Use of `$app = Factory::getApplication();`

Current `insertArticles` function

```
private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {

  $articleModel = new ArticleModel();

  foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article) {
    $articleData = [
      'id' => 0,
      'catid' => 13,
      'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
      'alias' => OutputFilter::stringURLSafe($article->title),
      'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
      'state' => 1,
      'access' => 1,
      'created_by' => 386,
      'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
      'language' => '*',
      'metadata' => [
        'xreference' => $article->dtnpfUrl,
      ],
      'attribs' => [
        'show_publish_date' => 1,
      ],
      'rules' => [
        'core.edit.delete' => [],
        'core.edit.edit' => [],
        'core.edit.state' => []
      ],
    ];

    if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
      throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
    } else {
      $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
    }
  }
  return $newIds ?? [];
}
```

**Updated**

Included use statements from the command file for reference:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ItemModel;
use Joomla\Component\Content\Site\Model;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Content;
use Joomla\CMS\Filter\OutputFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;
use Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand;
```

**Command line error**

`Class "Ploszmarketing\Plugin\Console\Dtnnews\CliCommand\ArticleModel" not found`

```
protected function doExecute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int {
  $symfonyStyle = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);

  $symfonyStyle->title('DTN News Import');

  // Fetch the JSON data and Run the insertArticle bulk data import to articles function
  $curlOpts = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.dtn.com/publishing/news/articles?categoryId=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C16%2C17&limit=10&maxAge=15&apikey=placeholder',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  ];

  try {
    $fetchedArticles = $this->curlToObject($curlOpts);
  
    if ($fetchedArticles) {
      $symfonyStyle->title(Text::_('Fetched Articles: ' . count($fetchedArticles)));
    }
  
    // Errors occur here
    $insertedIds = $this->insertArticles($fetchedArticles);
  
    if ($insertedIds) {
      $symfonyStyle->title(Text::_('Inserted IDs: ' . implode(', ', $insertedIds)));
    }
  
  } catch (exception $e) {
    $symfonyStyle->error(Text::_($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $symfonyStyle->success('Successful import!');

  return 0;

}

private function curlToObject(array $curlOpts): array {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $error = curl_error($ch); // Get the last error
  curl_close($ch);
  if ($error) {
    throw new Exception($error);
  }
  return json_decode($result);
}

private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {
  // Replaced articleModel method with recommendation
  // $articleModel = Content::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel');
  $articleModel = new ArticleModel();

  foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article) {
    $articleData = [
      'id' => 0,
      'catid' => 13,
      'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
      'alias' => OutputFilter::stringURLSafe($article->title),
      // I know strip_tags is deprecated for 8.2. I will fix after issues are resolved.
      'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
      'state' => 1,
      'access' => 1,
      'created_by' => 386,
      'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
      'language' => '*',
      'metadata' => [
        'xreference' => $article->dtnpfUrl,
      ],
      'attribs' => [
        'show_publish_date' => 1,
      ],
      'rules' => [
        'core.edit.delete' => [],
        'core.edit.edit' => [],
        'core.edit.state' => []
      ],
    ];

    if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
      throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
    } else {
      $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
    }
  }
  return $newIds ?? [];
}

private function removeDuplicateAliases(array $articles): array {
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $query
    ->select('a.alias')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid') . " = " . $db->quote('13'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $aliasLookup = array_flip($db->loadColumn());

  foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
    if (isset($aliasLookup[OutputFilter::stringURLSafe($article->title)])) {
      unset($articles[$i]);
    }
  }
  return $articles;
}
```

Error in the command line: `Call to a member function save() on bool`

Exception trace:

```
 at /var/www/upgrade/plugins/console/dtnnews_cli/src/CliCommand/RunDtnnewsCommand.php:126
 Ploszmarketing\Plugin\Console\Dtnnews\CliCommand\RunDtnnewsCommand->insertArticles() at /var/www/upgrade/plugins/console/dtnnews_cli/src/CliCommand/RunDtnnewsCommand.php:68
 Ploszmarketing\Plugin\Console\Dtnnews\CliCommand\RunDtnnewsCommand->doExecute() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Command/AbstractCommand.php:235
 Joomla\Console\Command\AbstractCommand->execute() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:1181
 Joomla\Console\Application->runCommand() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:403
 Joomla\Console\Application->doExecute() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php:206
 Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication->doExecute() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/vendor/joomla/console/src/Application.php:448
 Joomla\Console\Application->execute() at /var/www/upgrade/libraries/src/Application/ConsoleApplication.php:259
 Joomla\CMS\Application\ConsoleApplication->execute() at /var/www/upgrade/cli/joomla.php:76
```

I am unsure of how to handle the `for loop` with the new model in Joomla 4.

The Joomla 3 insertArticles function is below

```
private function insertArticles(array $articles): array {
  require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php';
  $articleModel = new ContentModelArticle([]);

  foreach ($this->removeDuplicateAliases($articles) as $article) {
    $articleData = [
      'id' => 0,
      'catid' => 13,
      'title' => ucwords(strtolower($article->title)),
      'alias' => JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($article->title),
      'introtext' => strip_tags($article->storySummary, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'fulltext' => strip_tags($article->content, ['p', 'img', 'table']),
      'note' => 'DTN supplied topics: ' . str_replace('/', ', ', $article->topic),
      'state' => 1,
      'access' => 1,
      'created_by' => 386,
      'created_by_alias' => 'DTN News',
      'language' => '*',
      'metadata' => [
        'xreference' => $article->dtnpfUrl,
      ],
      'attribs' => [
        'show_publish_date' => 1,
      ],
      'rules' => [
        'core.edit.delete' => [],
        'core.edit.edit' => [],
        'core.edit.state' => []
      ],
    ];

    if (!$articleModel->save($articleData)) {
      throw new Exception($articleModel->getError());
    } else {
      $newIds[] = $articleModel->getItem()->id;
    }
  }
  return $newIds ?? [];
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that you are trying to call `save()` from a boolean value, either true or false. The reason `$articleModel` is false is due to it not being created as you expected, returning a value of false instead of the Model object.

The reason it failed is because you have used the Joomla 3 class name for the model and not the Joomla 4 class name.

This line in your `insertArticles()`

```
  $articleModel = new ContentModelArticle([]);
```

needs to be changed to

```
  $articleModel = new ArticleModel();
```

*I have removed the array '[]'argument as I don't see that it is required in either version.*

In the `..\components\com_content\src\Model\ArticleModel.php` that you are referring to in the `require_once` line above the calling of the ArticleModel class you can see the name you need to be using.

```
/**
 * Content Component Article Model
 *
 * @since  1.5
 */
class ArticleModel extends ItemModel
{
    /**
```

**Update: 17th September**

There are several way you can achieve this within Joomla 4

```
$articleModel = new \Joomla\Component\Content\Administrator\Model\ArticleModel();
```

With a use statement that removes the need for the require_once statement.

```
use Joomla\Component\Content\Administrator\Model\ArticleModel;
...
$articleModel = new ArticleModel();
```

Or by getting the model from the dependency injection container

```
$mvcFactory = $this->app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();
$articleModel = $mvcFactory->createModel('Article', 'Administrator', ['ignore_request' => true]);
```

You can see an example of the last method in `..\plugins\sampledata\blog\blog.php` at line #679 onwards where it is used in code very similar to what you are doing by adding sample articles to the Joomla instance.

```
$mvcFactory = $this->app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory();

// Store the articles
foreach ($articles as $i => $article) {
            $articleModel = $mvcFactory->createModel('Article', 'Administrator', ['ignore_request' => true]);
...

    if (!$articleModel->save($article)) {
...
}
```

Comment: I have swapped out the code on the line and have updated my question with additional code. The CLi now shows an error `Class "Ploszmarketing\Plugin\Console\Dtnnews\CliCommand\ArticleModel" not found`. I used the namespace from content component article model.

Comment: Without seeing the code you have added it is hard to say what is going on now but from the message it looks like it looking for ArticleModel in the wrong namespace.
I will update my answer with some more details.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I went with the `use` statement and am encountering this error: `Joomla\CMS\Workflow\Workflow::__construct(): Argument #2 ($app) must be of type ?Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication, Joomla\CMS\Application\Con  
  soleApplication given, called in /var/www/upgrade/libraries/src/MVC/Model/WorkflowBehaviorTrait.php on line 90`. I have updated my question with additional code.

Comment: You now have a different issue that should probably be created as a new question on JSE however the short answer I think is to disable the Work Flow in Article:Options under the Integration's tab of the back end.

Comment: The Work Flow option was already disabled in Article > Options. I will test some more before opening another question. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Your problem appears to be that you are using the 'console' application when you create your instance of Joomla, and like the CLI, it doesn't have the concept of a site or admin environment which when using the the ArticleModel is trigger something that is looking for a site instance of Joomla. This question from a few months ago I try to explain differences between the four modes that you can use, https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/33140/how-to-create-an-instance-of-the-joomla-cms-from-the-browser-or-the-command-line